# Trying to translate "さすがに悪事を働いてそれを自分で解決するなんて真似はしない" as close to Japanese as possible

Tags: translation

Original Japanese sentence:

```
さすがに悪事を働いてそれを自分で解決するなんて真似はしない
```

English translation:

As expected, I **decided**(emphasis) that I **will not** conduct any crimes.

Some context:

> **A**: 「つまり誰かの不幸に居合わせる幸運が必要になる。それを解決してこその英雄ってわけだ」
>   **B**: 「おい、まさか……」
>   **A**: 「安心しろ、さすがに悪事を働いてそれを自分で解決するなんて真似はしない。それにそんなことしなくても、この世に完全な平和なんてありえない。必ずどこかしらで不幸なことは起きている」

Comment: "As close to Japanese as possible" in what sense?  Word for word?  In the over-all "feeling"?

Comment: Feeling. Sorry for not describing it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the line in question is certainly conversational, it is not slangy at all.  So I tried to maintain that speech style in my own TL attempt.

> "**(Fret not!)  As you would expect, I'm not stupid enough to play a cheap trick of doing evil and trying to settle it all by myself**."